# What is the permission scope of id-token in GitHub Action?

Tags: github, github-actions

What does the `id-token` mean in the example below and what is the use?

```yaml
jobs:
  job_id:
    # Add "id-token" with the intended permissions.
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'

    steps:
    - id: 'auth'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: 'projects/123456789/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/my-provider'
        service_account: 'my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

    - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0'

    - name: 'Use gcloud CLI'
      run: 'gcloud info'
```

The example is from [setup-gcloud](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud)

I try to have a look of [doc1](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#modifying-the-permissions-for-the-github_token) and [doc2](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps). However, I cannot find any useful information.

May you give me some hints/advice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `id-token` is used in combination with [OpenID Connect](https://docs.github.com/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect).

Setting the permissions to `write` is required in order to request an OpenID Connect JWT Token as described in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#adding-permissions-settings).

While the example you shared is from setup-gcloud, the part in your workflow that actually needs this, is the action [google-github-actions/auth](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth). In there, you want to look at the sections on "Workload Identity Federation". More docs are also available on GCP directly: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation